# ImageView state not changing

Tags: android, android-imageview

I've use a *selector* to change the drawable of an `ImageView`.

i.e. When the user press the image, the drawable should change.

In layout.xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="73dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_submit_selector" />
```

ic_submit_selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_submit_pressed" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_submit_pressed" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_submit" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_submit_pressed" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"/>

</selector>
```

But the drawable is not changing.

Comment: ImageView will not, use ImageButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="73dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_submit_selector" />
```

Not

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="73dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_submit_selector" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend Murtaza's correct answer, if you still wont be able to make it run, try replacing android:src with **android:background**.